# How to search for name from local storage using typeahead?

Tags: jquery

```
 var a=[{
             "Name":"Harsha",
             "Age":"18"
          },
          {
              "Name":"Havisha",
              "Age":"19"
          }

          ]; 
localStorage.setItem("list",JSON.stringify(a));   

    $("#namm").autocomplete({
           source:[
              b=localStorage.getItem("list")
        ]
        });
```

I have stored the names in local storage with name.Then now When i search for a name in a textbox the names must be searched from the localstorage.How can it possible .I have tried above>But I am not able to do it

Comment: seems a syntax error in the code.

Comment: But when I type  a letter on a input search the whole object is being displayed.

Comment: @NagaBhawani see what you are doing `[a=localStorage.get()..;]` variable assignment in the array and your array ends with `;` which causes error.

Comment: Sorry its just my mistake while writing code here.

Comment: @NagaBhawani if you could mention what kind of data you are storing in the localStorage?

Comment: I have edited the code once see it

Comment: @NagaBhawani Ah i see. Okay! You need to go to the documentation of autocomplete. You would see this for array which holds multiple objects. It says `An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }]`

Comment: But the thing is i have added those objects dynamically not static

Comment: @NagaBhawani, you can see the answer i have posted. that might help you some how. i guess....:)

Answer (score 0):

If your `list` is a String Array just try this:

```
var list = localStorage.getItem("list");
$("#namm").autocomplete({
    source: list
});
```

P.S. Always check that the variable returned from localStorage is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do it this way:

```
$(function() {

  var list = [{
    value: 'naga'
  }, {
    value: 'bhawani'
  }];
  localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));

  $("#namm").autocomplete({
    source: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"))
  });

});
```

---

> **Array:** An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>   An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
>   An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`
>   **The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu.** The **value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item**. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., **if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label**.

---

Another suggestion is if you are able to change the `json` data then you can use it like:

```
var list = [{
      value: 'Harsha : 18'
    }, {
      value: 'Havisha : 19'
    }];
```

---

#### [A plnkr for this.](http://plnkr.co/edit/hbxOUsEk2yarW2tqxaBY?p=preview)